# Search multiple phrases/terms with weights in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in using elastic-search. I am familiar with basic searching but what now I want is to search multiple terms in a single hit. i.e.
I have five search-terms 'first', 'second', 'third', 'four', 'five' and each term has some weight assigned to it. So rather than making a call one by one for each term, what I want a single query that will accept these terms along with their weights and return results according to the weights.

So it should look something like this (This is not the elastic-search syntax)

```
search
{
  terms: [(first , 3),(second , 1),(thirst , 4),(four , 2),(five , 5)],
  fields: [field1, field2, field3...]
}
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

The query string query [supports boosting in the following form](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

```
quick^2 fox
```